# Iterative Calculations using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration

I would like to know if the following calculation is possible using `dplyr`.

```
x <- data.frame(
  yr = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016),
  rate = c(1.1, 1.2, 0.8, -0.4, 0.5)
) %>% arrange(desc(yr))
```

This is how I want to calculate y:

```
y[i] = ifelse(yr == max(yr), 100,
    100 * y[i-1]/(100 + rate[i-1]))
```

If I try something like this:

```
x %>%
  mutate(
    y = ifelse(
      yr == max(yr), 100,
      100 * lag(y) / (100 + lag(rate)) 
    )
  )
```

it returns the following error: `Evaluation error: object 'y' not found.`

As reflected in the title, I would like a dplyr solution inside a pipe without using packages like `zoo` or `data.table` mainly for its SQL translatability with different databases.
Would this be possible?

Comment: In the `ifelse`, 'y' is not yet created.  If the value of 'y' should be based on the earlier value, then you may need `accumulate`.  It is not clear whether `accumulate` would be able to translate or not

Comment: I did understand the error message but it was just unclear how I could fix the issue. You're right - `accumulate` didn't seem to translate, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cumprod` like this:

```
x %>% mutate(y = 100 * cumprod(100 / (100 + lag(rate, default = 0))))
```

giving:

```
    yr rate         y
1 2016  0.5 100.00000
2 2015 -0.4  99.50249
3 2014  0.8  99.90210
4 2013  1.2  99.10922
5 2012  1.1  97.93401
```

Regarding databases, I doubt dplyr can do that but you could use sql directly with the database.  Here is an example using sqldf with the sqlite back end.  The same code also works with the H2 database back end.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.yr, a.rate, 100 * coalesce(exp(sum(log(100/(100 + b.rate)))), 1) y 
      from x a left join x b on a.yr < b.yr group by a.yr 
      order by a.yr desc")
```

giving:

```
    yr rate         y
1 2016  0.5 100.00000
2 2015 -0.4  99.50249
3 2014  0.8  99.90210
4 2013  1.2  99.10922
5 2012  1.1  97.93401
```

Comment: I couldn't get the `cumprod` nor sql statement to execute correctly in Postgres DB... Could you explain how you got the function for y?
Still, `cumprod` worked like a charm in Spark. Thanks for that!

Comment: @g-grothendieck & When I ask about function for y, I mean [`100 * coalesce(exp(sum(log(100/(100 + b.rate)))), 1)`].

Comment: sqlite does not have an aggregate function for `prod` but `exp(sum(log(...))` converts `sum` to it.  `coalesce` returns its first non-null argument.

Comment: I was especially confused by `exp(sum(log(...))` but thank you for your explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to use `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
   mutate(y = accumulate(rate[-n()], 
              ~  100 * .x/(100 + .y), 
                 .init = 100))
#   yr rate         y
#1 2016  0.5 100.00000 
#2 2015 -0.4  99.50249
#3 2014  0.8  99.90210
#4 2013  1.2  99.10922
#5 2012  1.1  97.93401
```

---

It can also be done in `base R` with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(u, v) 100 * u/(100 + v) , x$rate[-nrow(x)],init = 100, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 100.00000  99.50249  99.90210  99.10922  97.93401
```

---

Based on the OP's logic, 1st element is initialized as 100

```
>  100 * (100)/(100 + 0.5)  # 2nd element
[1] 99.50249
>  100 * 99.50249/(100 - 0.4) # 3rd element
[1] 99.9021
>  100 * 99.9021/(100 + 0.8) # 4th element
[1] 99.10923
>  100 * 99.10923/(100 + 1.2) # 5th element
[1] 97.93402
```

Comment: I like use of `purrr::accumulate` since it allows us to use pipes, but it only seems to work for R objects. Sorry about that, should have created a better reproducible code by creating a local Postgres DB. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @creativename  No problem.  Glad to help you.  I didn't test it on the Postgres.  Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use `for` loop

```r
library(dplyr)

#initialize column "y"
x$y <- NA

#process one row at a time
for (i in seq(nrow(x))) {
  x[i,] <- (x[seq(i),] %>%
              mutate(y = ifelse(yr==max(yr), 100, 100 * lag(y) / (100 + lag(rate)))))[i,]
}
x
```

Output is:

```
    yr rate         y
1 2016  0.5 100.00000
2 2015 -0.4  99.50249
3 2014  0.8  99.90210
4 2013  1.2  99.10922
5 2012  1.1  97.93401
```

Sample data:

```
x <- structure(list(yr = c(2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012), rate = c(0.5, 
-0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .Names = c("yr", "rate"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't do this with x being a table from Postgres, but I agree that this could have been a solution with any other R object.

Comment: @creativename Oh I see. Glad that you found an answer. Cheers!